# Certificate uploaded to Azure Key Vault has different content when downloading as a secret

Tags: c#, azure, ssl-certificate, azure-keyvault, pfx

I uploaded a .pfx certificate to the Azure Key Vault using the Azure portal. The certificate is 3558 bytes in size. When I download the certificate as a secret using C#:

```
public async Task SaveCertificateAsync(string key)
{
    var secret = await _secretClient.GetSecretAsync(key);
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(secret.Value.Value);
    File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\certificates\\test.pfx", bytes);
}
```

I get another 3558 byte file. This file however does not have the same structure as the original certificate and does not work in my application. I know that when using the `GetCertificateAsync` method I would get the certificate without the private key but I thought that by downloading it as a secret I would get the original, valid certificate file. Why has it changed?

Comment: have you tried storing as Certificate in Key Vault instead of as a Secret?

Comment: It is stored as a Certificate, when storing as a certificate you can still access it as a secret.

Comment: Didn't know that.  What about this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/security.keyvault.certificates-readme?view=azure-dotnet which is for certificates?  Never used so don't know if it would give any different response than what you have.

Comment: And this seems like it might be promising https://github.com/azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/keyvault/samples/getcert

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to download the Certificate from Azure Key Vault as a secret and turn it into a X509Certificate2 certificate. Do upload/import your cert to AKV as a certificte.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Helper method to get a certificate
    /// 
    /// Source https://github.com/heaths/azsdk-sample-getcert/blob/master/Program.cs
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="certificateClient"></param>
    /// <param name="secretClient"></param>
    /// <param name="certificateName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateAsync(CertificateClient certificateClient,
                                                            SecretClient secretClient,
                                                            string certificateName)
    {

        KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy certificate = certificateClient.GetCertificate(certificateName);

        // Return a certificate with only the public key if the private key is not exportable.
        if (certificate.Policy?.Exportable != true)
        {
            return new X509Certificate2(certificate.Cer);
        }

        // Parse the secret ID and version to retrieve the private key.
        string[] segments = certificate.SecretId.AbsolutePath.Split('/', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (segments.Length != 3)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Number of segments is incorrect: {segments.Length}, URI: {certificate.SecretId}");
        }

        string secretName = segments[1];
        string secretVersion = segments[2];

        KeyVaultSecret secret = secretClient.GetSecret(secretName, secretVersion);

        // For PEM, you'll need to extract the base64-encoded message body.
        // .NET 5.0 preview introduces the System.Security.Cryptography.PemEncoding class to make this easier.
        if ("application/x-pkcs12".Equals(secret.Properties.ContentType, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            byte[] pfx = Convert.FromBase64String(secret.Value);
            return new X509Certificate2(pfx);
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException($"Only PKCS#12 is supported. Found Content-Type: {secret.Properties.ContentType}");
    }
```